# Duplicate mysql results being returned with two left joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to determine if a user has liked a post but I'm getting duplicate results returned...Am I missing something or is there a better (more efficient) way of retrieving this data?

```
SELECT 
p.*, 
u.firstname, 
u.lastname, 
l.post_id AS liked 
FROM `posts` p 
LEFT JOIN `users` u ON u.id = p.author_id 
LEFT JOIN `likes` l ON l.user_id = p.author_id 
WHERE p.author_id=1 AND p.published = 1 
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

MySQL Tables:

```
**users table**
id, firstname, lastname

**posts table**
id, author_id, post, published, post_date

**likes table**
id, post_id, user_id, timestamp
```

Here is the output:

```
id, author_id, post, firstname, lastname, liked
"36","1","sdfsdf","John","Smith","36"
"36","1","sdfsdf","John","Smith","4"
"27","1","xcvxvc","John","Smith","36"
"27","1","xcvxvc","John","Smith","4"
"29","1","sdfsdf","John","Smith","36"
"29","1","sdfsdf","John","Smith","4"
"3","1",""fdgdfg","John","Smith","36"
"3","1",""fdgdf","John","Smith","4"
"28","1","data","John","Smith","36"
"28","1","data","John","Smith","4"
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: you're selecting all of that users's likes, basically. probably you need a `posts.id = ?` in the where clause to limit to that particular post.

Comment: I'm trying to grab the 10 most recent posts...can this not be done?

Comment: `group by l.post_id` may help. but it would be easier if you show your actual result data (obfuscate personal data).

Comment: You can use regular inner joins, since you only want true matches!

Comment: @jarlh The inner join does in fact grab the uniques but only grabs entries where there is an entry in the likes table.  I'm trying to grab ten results and  regardless if it does or does not have an entry in the likes tables...thoughts?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize you could use conditional statements on JOINs so I ended up doing this to solve my issue:

```
SELECT 
p.*, 
u.firstname, 
u.lastname, 
l.post_id AS liked 
FROM `posts` p 
LEFT JOIN `users` u ON u.id = p.author_id 
LEFT JOIN `likes` l ON l.user_id = p.author_id 
  AND l.post_id = p.id 
WHERE p.author_id=1 
AND p.published = 1 
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typical configuration which defines a many-to-many relationship between `posts` and `users`. However, there is a particular way to join these tables together, using the intersection table `likes` which you don't quite have down.

An intersection table contains two foreign keys, one to each of the two tables that relate to each other. In the case of `likes`, this is the user_id and post_id fields which reference the `users` table and `posts` table respectively. To properly join these tables, the `likes` joins to the `users` table using the user_id field and the `posts` table using the post_id field.

The order of the tables is not really significant to resolve the relationships -- to a point. In your case, because you want all the posts listed even if there are no "likes" associated with them, then the `posts` table goes first. Never, however, can the intersection table go last. It must precede both entity tables or go between them in the list. Each entity table joins to the intersection table, not to each other.

Like so:

```
SELECT  p.*, u.firstname + ' ' + u.lastname AS LikedBy 
FROM    `posts` p 
LEFT JOIN `likes` l
    ON  l.post_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN `users` u
    ON  u.id = l.user_id 
WHERE   ...
```